# Laurent series about a singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I have a function $$f(z)=\frac{z^2-2z+5}{z-1}$$ and i'm supposed to use Laurent series to expand it at the singularity $z=1$

I tried to use geometric series, didn't work then i thought i could turn it into

$$f(z)=\frac{z(z-1)+5}{z-1}=z+\frac{5}{z-1}=z+\frac{1}{i}\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-1-i}{i}}=z-\frac{1}{i}\sum (\frac{z-1-i}{i})^n$$

But that's the most unfortunate thing i've seen in my life...So....

I'm also supposed to determine the residue and use it to calculate the integral along the unit circle around $z=1$ so i guess i can't use what i did to do that...

I guess i used the wrong series manipulation to do this...appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the center supposed to be $z=1$ or $z=1+i$?

Comment: It might help to let $u=z-1,$ so that $z=u+1$ can be plugged into the numerator. Then proceed to get Laurent for this in terms of $u$, then plug back.

Comment: the expansion should be about $z=1$ that $i$ thing is me using $z-1=z-1-i+i$ to avoid the singularity

Comment: $z+\frac{5}{z-1}$ is already a Laurent series, you don't need to go further. Unfortunately, it is wrong because $z^2-2z+z \neq z(z-1)+5$.

Comment: eh should be $z(z-2)$ ....ehh me potato head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that $z^2-2z+5=(z-1)^2+4\ne z(z-1)+5$.  Then, we can write

$$\frac{z^2-2z+5}{z-1}=(z-1)+\frac4{z-1}$$

which constitutes the Laurent series around $z=1$.  And it is easy to see that the residue is $4$.

Comment: hey thanks!!! Thou all the laurent series exercises ive done so far would give me the annulus and simply have me do series manipulation and use geometric series to expand it......

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  In this case, this is valid for $z\ne 1$.

Comment: @JerryHolmes The region of convergence is still an annulus. The inner radius is zero and the outer radius is infinite. As usual, the radii go all the way to the nearest singularities $z=1$ and $z=\infty$.

Comment: @MarkViola No. That is for a Laurent series centered at $z=0$. This is a Laurent series centered at $z=1$.

Comment: @owl Yes, I know.

Comment: @MarkViola Sorry to come back to you again, i just wanted to ask there is a series for $z>1$ too then?

Comment: @JerryHolmes The expansion here is correct for all $z$ in the domain, which is $z\ne 1$.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks yeah you see i know that when i look at the definitions and formulas but still asked for some reason sry about that